Wix3 Installer: how to define an optional custom action
I have a wix3 installer which install the main software together with a third party software.
I would like that the third party software could be installed optionally. The Yes/No installation dialog for this third party software appears but is I set "no" the whole installation is aborted.
This third party software is installed with a custom action:
 <CustomAction Id="InvokeStandaloneMythirdpartyInstall" Impersonate="no" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="CustomActionCom0ComInstall" Return="ignore" />
which is called in the "InstallExecuteSequence":
<InstallExecuteSequence >                                  <Custom Action="DisablePreviousScheduledTask" Before="InstallFiles"/>         <Custom Action='InvokeStandaloneMythirdpartyInstall' After="InstallFiles">             <![CDATA[NOT(COM0COM_INSTALLED = "#50331648") AND NOT(REMOVE)]]> </Custom>                 </InstallExecuteSequence>
It would be possible to press "no" for the third party software and install only the main software?
